# Prevent clicking on element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm just wondering is there any feature in React.js that allows you block user from clicking on some part of app?

To be more clear I'm working on Tic tac toe app and I would like to block any other clicks to game field if someone wins.

After checkWinner function detects a win, winner is displayed above game field like this

[image]

and from now I would like to make that user can click only replay icon or return icon. nothing else.

**Part of my checkWinner function in which I've tried to use e.stopPropagation()**

```
  function checkWinner(e){
    //Horizontal check
    for(let i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      let xCount=0;
      let oCount=0;

      for(let j=0;j<values[i].length;j++){
        if(typeof values[i][j] === 'object' && values[i][j].props.children === 'x'){
          xCount++;
        }

        if(typeof values[i][j] === 'object' && values[i][j].props.children === 'o'){
          oCount++;
        }
      }

      if(xCount === 3){
        setWinner('X WINS!');
        displayWinner();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
```

This function is called after every click to field, so after every click it checks if someone wins. But this throws me an Error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined**

Do you guys know about any other approach for this situation? Thanks.

Comment: The react tutorial covers this same sample app. Have you checked their [approach](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#declaring-a-winner)?

Comment: **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined"**  That error strikes me as very clear.  Are you passing in the event object where you call `checkWinner()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable click you can use CSS property `pointer-events: none;`

Example to disable click

```
 function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  }
  let disableClass = counter < 5 ? '' : 'disable';
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Disable button to click after 5</h1>
      <button 
      className={disableClass}
      onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <h3>{counter}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css

```
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

you can follow this and make changes as per your requirement.
for more reference check this [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-click-5zyc1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask you for one more thing? :/

Comment: @Pinncik yeah tell me.

Comment: Do you have any experience with animating react-router-dom routes with react-spring?