# User clicks in React UI layer affecting lower WebGL layer

Tags: reactjs, three.js, webgl

I have a React app that contains a WebGl experience.

The interface for the WebGl is in the parent React component, which passes props down into the WebGl.

React UI
|
--- > WebGL

Whenever I click in the React UI ( such as some button ) the click also registers in the WebGL and causes unwanted actions in the 3D environment.

Any idea how I can prevent this?

Thank you!

Comment: Will pointer-events: none work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent clicking on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486572/prevent-clicking-on-element)

Comment: No, pointer-events none, when set on the UI that float on top of the webGL canvas does not prevent click from being picked up by the canvas.